# Python - Pulling lowest integer from a list and then "pop"ing it to another

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

As the topic suggests I am attempting to take integers (in tuples) from one list and to to add them to another using the pop function

Here's what I have so far and am stuck doing so.

```
loga = [(912, "Message A1") , (1000, "Message A2") , (988, "Message A3") , (1012, "Message A4") , (1002, "Message A5")]

logb = [(926, "Message B1") , (1008, "Message B2") , (996, "Message B3") , (1019, "Message B4") , (1100, "Message B5")]

logc = [(1056,"Message C1") , (1033, "Message C2") , (999, "Message C3") , (1054, "Message C4") , (1086, "Message C5")]

logs = [loga, logb, logc]

def find_lowest_i(logs):
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        log = lst(i)

if len(log) > t = log[0][0]

    if i==0 or t < lowest_t
    lowest_i = i
    lowest_t = t

return i
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
loga = [(912, "Message A1") , (1000, "Message A2") , (988, "Message A3") , (1012, "Message A4") , (1002, "Message A5")]

logb = [(926, "Message B1") , (1008, "Message B2") , (996, "Message B3") , (1019, "Message B4") , (1100, "Message B5")]

logc = [(1056,"Message C1") , (1033, "Message C2") , (999, "Message C3") , (1054, "Message C4") , (1086, "Message C5")]

logs = [loga, logb, logc]
final=[]
for log in logs:
    for tup in log:
        final.append(tup[0])
lowest_number=min(int(x) for x in final)
return lowest_number
```

That should do the trick for you, it works by iterating over `loga,logb,logc` through the `logs` list, appending the numbers to the `final` list, then using a list comprehension with the `min()` function to get the lowest number.